# php webservices with android

Tags: php, android, web-services

I'm new to PHP programming and have poor knowledge about it, but I want to use it to make web services to my client Android application...

I began making my first web service with PHP and it's working fine, but I want to know how I can make one file that has all my functions and methods that I need and how to call it from Android

Thank you

This is functions.php

```
    <?php
   function GetAllRest()
    {
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    mysql_select_db("myhoteldb");
     $sql=mysql_query("SELECT rest_id ,rest_name,cuisine,no_tables,bg_img,rest_logo      FROM  restaurant");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  $output[]=$row;
  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close();
}
function GetAllCategory($lang_id,$rest_id)
{
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    mysql_select_db("myhoteldb");
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT cat_lang.rowid ,cat_lang.cat_id as _id,lang_id,   cat_name,cat_description from cat_lang  ,menu_category WHERE lang_id= $lang_id  AND  restaurant= $rest_id ");

      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
     $output[]=$row;
     print(json_encode($output));
      mysql_close();

  }



   ?>
```

and the URL 
     http://localhost/mywebservices.php?op=GetAllCategory&lang_id=1&rest_id=1

and i got this error now

```
   Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\functions.php on line 22

```
   Notice: Undefined variable: output in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions.php on line 24
    null
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an idea, I'd recommend including the function name desired to run in your url.
And then, get that function name and arguments, pass them to php's

```
call_user_func_array()
```

function.

Here's a very basic idea of a function handler:

your request URL would look like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/webservice.php?op=CallFunctionOne&param_a=test&param_b=test2
```

And here is the handler to route your calls to your functions:

```
require_once("./functions.php");

if(!empty($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])){
    $query_str = stripslashes($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    parse_str($query_str,$args);
    $op = array_shift($args);
    if(is_callable ($op)){
        call_user_func_array($op,$args);
    }
    else{
        echo "Handler error.<br />";
        echo $op . " function is not callable.";
    }
}
```

And functions.php file would include your functions.
Hope it will give some idea.

Comment: can you  explain more . with total example as i told you i have poor knowledge in php

Comment: and if i have functions that didn't take args what it will be

Comment: you can just pass an empty array. If I explain more, basically what I showed you is a simple call handler based on URL. "op" is the function name you want to call from your android application. Once you make a request, your php application will parse the url and get the function name. Based on the function name, it'll callback that function which would be located in your functions.php file.

Comment: i used your way but i got this error Handler error.
GetAllCategory function is not callable.

Comment: Where is that function located?

Comment: i located my functions in functions.php  and this file on htdocs

Comment: look the first function works fine now but i think i have a problem in the parameters in the second select function

Comment: Really Thanks for you Selcuk you really help me and solve my problem ..now every thing works fine it was an error in the sql statement .. thanks thanks thanks ... nice to meet you :))

Comment: do u have any idea to how to call this functions from my android client app

Answer (score 1):

If you know PHP then I assume you'll know HTML.

PhoneGap allows you to run apps on andriod using HTML, Javascript and CSS. http://phonegap.com/start

Using the Javascript you could make a page request to your web php file.

Here is a jQuery example

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/myfile.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.rest_name); // do whatever you want with the json response
  }
});
</script>
```

To enable the cross-domain you need to add this into the php files header (unsure if Apps need cross-domain validation tho)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```